# How to make Firefox showAlertNotification text as mutiple lines?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, alert

I'm working on a mail notifier.
Here is part of code:

```
alertsService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alertsservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService),
alertsService.showAlertNotification("chrome://mailnotifier/skin/sample-small.jpg", info,mail_title, false, "", null, "");
```

The problem is "showAlertNotification" and based on [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIAlertsService) in MDC :

> **text**
>  The text to display in the
>   alert, explaining the alert condition.
>   The text must not be too long,
>   otherwise it might be truncated to a
>   platform-specific length. If the text
>   is too long, try to use line returns
>   in the text to have it split and
>   displayed over multiple lines.*

I tried `br,br/,"\n","\r"` .etc for **line return**, they all failed to make the line break, Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The XUL sliding alert does not support multiline text. I can't speak for the platform-specific implementations available (with appropriate packages installed) on the Mac and Linux.

You could always try forking the [implementation](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/find?string=resources/content/alert) of the XUL sliding alert; Thunderbird does that for its [new mail alert](http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/find?string=content/newmailalert).